# Matching two arrays to create a third array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, match

I have an array:

```
var array = [black, white]
```

and an object:

```
var object = [
    {color: black, hex: #000000},
    {color: white, hex: #ffffff},
    {color: red, hex: #ff0000}
]
```

What I want to do is create a new object from colors that match in both the array and the object, so in this example the new object would be:

```
var object = [
    {color: black, hex: #000000},
    {color: white, hex: #ffffff}
]
```

Comment: You could create a new array objectFiltered, loop over object and do a conditional check on array.indexOf(object[i].color) > -1 if true then push the current index to objectFlitered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the object thusly:

```js
var array = ['black', 'white']

var object = [
    {color: 'black', hex: '#000000'},
    {color: 'white', hex: '#ffffff'},
    {color: 'red', hex: '#ff0000'}
]

var result = object.filter(function(entry) {
  return array.indexOf(entry.color) > -1;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this purpose,

```
var arr = ["black", "white"];
var obj = [
    {color: "black", hex: "#000000"},
    {color: "white", hex: "#ffffff"},
    {color: "red", hex: "#ff0000"}
];

var res = obj.filter(itm => arr.includes(itm.color));
console.log(res); //[{color: "black", hex: "#000000"}, {color: "white", hex: "#ffffff"}]
```

Comment: `filter` and `includes` (which IE doesn't support)

Comment: @j08691 IE >=9 supports `filter` and `indexOf`. OP can make use of that if he wants to write a code in ES<6 environment.

Answer (score -1):

Use filter:

```
var array = ['black', 'white'];
var objectArray = [
    {color: 'black', hex: '#000000'},
    {color: 'white', hex: '#ffffff'},
    {color: 'red', hex: '#ff0000'}
];

var result = objectArray.filter(function(item) {
    return array.some(function(i) {
        return i === item.color;
  })
});


console.log(result);
```

NB I had to add quotes to some of your example data.